# How do i add different headers to different pages?

Tags: libreoffice

I want *page-1* to be marked *Index*, *page 2-10* to be marked *'FOOBAR'*, *page 11-15* to be marked *'RUBBISH'* etc in the header of the page. My page numbers are in the footer and i'd like all pages to be numbered 1,2,3,4, etc (which right now is the case)

Answer (score 6):

Select page by clicking in it - then press F11 to bring up the 'Styles' box - choose a style or create a new style and double click to apply it to that page **BUT make sure you set Style Category to 'Page Styles'**.

Select another page - F11 - this time select "Default" so that style is applied to all subsequent pages after the selected page.

Now go to the page you want whose style you want to alter, after "Default" styled pages; select page, **Insert->Manual Break** a popup opens and pick a style that you want to apply.

This will style the various "Headers" for each page - to add the content, select the "Header" and just type text into it..'FOOBAR' 'Index' whatever..

Comment: The whole process is confusing, but I upvoted for the tip of `Insert->Manual Break`.